# Mvc list with multiple properties

Tags: c#, list, model-view-controller

How can i add more properties to my mvc list? Now im adding all 3 three different values to "value" property to "myList". I want the list myList have properties like: Text = item, Value1 = item.resourceid, Value2 = allQuestionsid, Value3 = allCategoriesIDs.

```
  List<SelectListItem> myList = new List<SelectListItem>();

  foreach (var item in searchList.resources)
        { 
               string allQuestionIDs = String.Join(", ", item.associatedQuestions.Select(q => q.id.ToString()));
               string allCategoriesIDs = String.Join(", ", item.associatedQuestions.Select(q => q.categoryid.ToString()));

               myList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item.linktext.ToString(), Value = String.Join(", ", item.resourceid, "AllQuestionsID " + allQuestionIDs, "AllCategoriesID " + allCategoriesIDs) });
         }
         return System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode(myList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there some reason you cannot create your own class to put in the list?

Class:

```
public class MySelectListItem
{
  public string Text { get; set; }

  public string Value1 { get; set; }

  public string Value2 { get; set; }

  public string Value3 { get; set; }

  public string Value4 { get; set; }
}
```

List:

```
  var myList = new List<MyCustomSelectListItem>();

  foreach (var item in searchList.resources)
  {
    string allQuestionIDs = String.Join(", ", item.associatedQuestions.Select(q => q.id.ToString()));
    string allCategoriesIDs = String.Join(", ", item.associatedQuestions.Select(q => q.categoryid.ToString()));

    myList.Add(new MyCustomSelectListItem
    {
      Text = item.linktext.ToString(), 
      Value1 = String.Join(", ", item.resourceid, "AllQuestionsID " + allQuestionIDs, "AllCategoriesID " + allCategoriesIDs),
      Value2 = "More Stuff",
      Value3 = "Even More Stuff",
      Value4 = "The End"
    });
  }
  return System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode(myList);
```